# Measure using datetime in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table like in the attached image:

[image]

As you can see, I have power consumptions of houses by hour.
What I would like to do is create a measure to calculate the average of power consumption by day and other measure to sum this average of power consumption by days depending on a time interval introduced in a filter.

I know it could be easy by don't know how to start with this.

Thanks for your help!
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding **Calculated columns** for Date and Time only:

```
Date = DATEVALUE(FORMAT('Table'[Datetime], "YYYY-MM-DD"))
Time = TIMEVALUE(FORMAT('Table'[Datetime], "hh:mm"))
```

With this you create a new **Calculated table** for consumption per day

```
Consumption per day = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Date],
    "Avg. Consumption", AVERAGE('Table'[Consumption])
)
```

and consumption per day for a given time interval

```
Consumption per day and time interval = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Date],
        "Avg. Consumption", AVERAGE('Table'[Consumption])
    ),
    'Table'[Time] >= TIMEVALUE("00:00"),
    'Table'[Time] <= TIMEVALUE("01:00")
)
```